# How to match the size of an SVG and its child tag, PATH

Tags: css, svg

There are some files that have problems when you take an SVG file and set the width and height like this.

```js
(next.js)

<SearchIcon width={25} height={25} />
```

Not all svg files are like this, but sometimes a few files don't match the width and height I set for the svg and the size of the child `path` just below the `svg` tag.

The `svg` size is what I set, but the `path` size is not what I expected. This results in different sizes for each SVG file, making it quite tricky to apply CSS styles.

How to match the size of `svg` and `path`?
Below is the `svg file` code in question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Uploaded to: SVG Repo, www.svgrepo.com, Generator: SVG Repo Mixer Tools -->
<svg width="800px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none">
  <path fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 9a5 5 0 1110 0A5 5 0 014 9zm5-7a7 7 0 104.2 12.6.999.999 0 00.093.107l3 3a1 1 0 001.414-1.414l-3-3a.999.999 0 00-.107-.093A7 7 0 009 2z"/>
</svg>
```

[image]
[image]

I tried the code below in CSS, but it doesn't apply

```css
svg {
    path {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Remove the attributes `width="800px" height="800px"` from the `svg`.

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript approach:

```html
<svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none">
  <path fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 9a5 5 0 1110 0A5 5 0 014 9zm5-7a7 7 0 104.2 12.6.999.999 0 00.093.107l3 3a1 1 0 001.414-1.414l-3-3a.999.999 0 00-.107-.093A7 7 0 009 2z" />
</svg>
  
<script>
  var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
  var bbox = svg.getBBox();
  var viewBox = [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" ");
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
</script>
```